# How to get text field in database in this code?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database consist of 4 filed that one of them is Text, now I want by use is query get Text filed and show in TextView, how should I do it?
Please help me!

**my source code:**

---

```
value = getIntent().getStringExtra("position");

    Load_Database();
    db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();



    Cursor  c = db.rawQuery("select text from movie_list where name  = '"+value+"'" , null);

    ????????


private void Load_Database() throws Error {
    myDbHelper = new MovieDB(DisplayActivity.this);
    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
   do{
      String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text"));
      //do stuff... 
   }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```